# YouTube - how to sort latest published videos which are preloaded as private in bulk

Tags: sorting, youtube

On my YouTube Playlist, I've preloaded 70+ videos and they're set as Private. When I change them to Public, I would expect the date to change to that date (e.g Mar 5, 2022). However, as you can see by the screenshots below, this is not happening.
Example:

**Visibility = PRIVATE**

- Video 1 -- Private -- Oct 27, 2021
- Video 2 -- Private -- Nov 10, 2021

**Visibility = PUBLIC**

- Video 1 -- Public -- Jan 26, 2022
- Video 2 -- Public -- Feb 10, 2022

Why is this a problem? On my site, I'm using iFrame code to display the Most Recent video. So when I sort the videos in the Playlist by "Date Published (Newest)" the results are random and not what I'm expecting. So, with the YouTube Published Dates not reflecting the current date, I'm not sure how I can retrieve the most recent video daily without doing it manually (heck, I hope not).

Is there a way to change the Published Date? My goal is to be able to set the Published Date (one date per video) and sort them by "Date Published (Newest)" so I can display the newest video on my website daily.

Any suggestions?  Thanks

**UPDATE Mar-5:**

OK, I see on these forum links that there is **NO WAY** to change the **PUBLISHED DATE** in YouTube:
https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/152028606?hl=en
https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/99275150?hl=en

Is uploading videos one per day for 365 days the only way to display the **MOST RECENT** video in a Channel or Playlist? If so, this makes it virtually impossible schedule posts in advance easily (i.e. YouTube > Website > Social Media > Email) because in my case, it's dependent on the MOST RECENT video being available in advance and easily identifiable.

Is there a programmatic way to achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I clarified my original post. Let me know if you need any additional information. Thanks

Comment: @JulesC can you add the embed link you're using? - because I have an idea: let's say your iframe link looks like this: `https://youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID&list=YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID&index=INDEX_VALUE` = then, you could create a javascript code that sets the `VIDEO_ID` and `INDEX_VALUE` according to your needs. ONly you knows the video order to show. Then, you could do something like this example: `myPrivateVideos = {"video_id_1", "video_id_2", "video_id_3"}; myLink = "https://youtube.com/watch?v="+myPrivateVideos[myPrivateVideos.length-1]. = this would bring the latest video in the array`

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes thank you so much for your response!!! I'm new at this and very interested in learning. I just want to confirm my naive understanding for...
v=VIDEO_ID&list=YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID&
So for YOUR _PLAYLIST_ID&, is this where I add my Playlist?

myPrivateVideos = {"video_id_1", "video_id_2", "video_id_3"};
"video_id_1" - If the URL = https://youtu.be/VG_blE4KkiE, would my video_id_1 be VG_blE4KkiE?

Sorry for the naive questions. I truly appreciate you help!!! THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @JulesC yes, the URL would be = `https://youtu.be/VG_blE4KkiE` - you're correct.